# Dropdown list where options populate a second list js/php?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a 2 dropdown lists side by side. When user selects from the first list, i need the second list's options to be displayed.

The sub-options will be retrieved from a database. I have a page that will return the necessary html given the specific parent. I just need the first list's selection to trigger an update of list #2.

Whats the best way of accomplishing this?

```
<select id="parent" name="list1">
    <option value="1">Parent 1</option>
    <option value="2">Parent 2</option>
    <option value="3">Parent 3</option>
    <option value="4">Parent 4</option>
</select>

<select id="child" name="list2">
</select>
```

caveat: cant use a form, cause the selection's are part of another form.

Comment: @Patrick - can you use jQuery? I notice you've asked other jQuery questions here today.

Comment: Could you please clarify why the fact that selects are in different form prevents you from submitting the first form and generating the other depending on the selected item of the first one?

Comment: I was under the impression that you could not have forms within forms as it would cause problems picking which one to submit.

Comment: @karim79 I find and hold onto working snippets for dear life, lol. Thats really the extent of my JS knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way to do this is to do an AJAX request after the first dropdown is selected to retrieve the contents of the second.

Exactly how you do that will depend on the frameworks/libraries you're using, but here's an example of a jQuery plugin designed for it:

[jQuery cascade plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cascade)

There's also a number of related questions on SO that may help:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cascading+dropdown

Comment: thank you for clarifying that this is called, that will help greatly in my search efforts!

Answer (score 1):

Use the event onchange of the select to call an ajax function to retrieve the new data

Answer (score 0):

A dead simple way is to set up your script to output the entire markup of the generated select list, and inject that into a wrapper element, e.g.:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <select id="child" name="list2">
    </select>
</div>

$("#parent').change(function() {
    $('#wrapper').load('getSelect.php','selection=' + $(this).val());
    return false; // may or may not be needed
});
```