# select lis menu echo

Tags: php, mysql

i have a 2 types of select list menus:

```
<select name="category">
<option>----Select----</option>
<option>Category 1</option>
<option>Category 2</option>
<option>Category 3</option>
<option>Category 4</option>
</select>

<select name="category_product">
<option>----Select----</option>
<option>Product of category 1</option>
<option>Product of category 1</option>
<option>Product of category 1</option>
<option>Product of category 1</option>
</select>
```

What i liked to to is when i choose  "Category 1" of the select list menu, it echos the select list menu "category_product", how can i do this?

I was thinking in put the category_product list menu in a variable, and when i chose a category it echo´s the category_products list menu, but i dont no how to make this detect when the category is chosen.

Hope for some help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dropdown list where options populate a second list js/php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656934/dropdown-list-where-options-populate-a-second-list-js-php)

Comment: What do you mean by `"echos the select list menu "category_product""`

Comment: you don't want to add a select menu via AJAX, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP or MySQL?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your only way is doing this with JS or jQuery, here is en example doing it with JS,

```
function showProducts(cat){
   document.getElementById(cat).style.display = 'block';
}

<select name="category" onchange="showProducts(this.value)">
<option>----Select----</option>
<option value="category_product">Category 1</option>
<option>Category 2</option>
<option>Category 3</option>
<option>Category 4</option>
</select>

<select style="display:none" id="category_product" name="category_product">
<option>----Select----</option>
<option>Product of category 1</option>
<option>Product of category 1</option>
<option>Product of category 1</option>
<option>Product of category 1</option>
</select>
```

Or another option what you have to make an AJAX call if you want the result should be straight from the database.

**UPDATE:**

Use this function instead of the above,

```
function showProducts(cat){
   for(var i=1;i<document.getElementsByTagName('select').length;i++){
     document.getElementsByTagName('select')[i].style.display = 'none';
   };
   document.getElementById(cat).style.display = 'block';
}
```

You can play around with it let me know for any further help.

Comment: itsme very nice, i used it and works but one more thing, i created one more select list menu

But the problem is when i choose onother category, the first one   i choosed before stays there, how can i make the pass categorys selected disapear and only appear what i select

Comment: I updated my answer take a look on it, and make sure you accept the answer and upvoting it, thank you

Comment: Sorry. it was one mistake please copy it and paste again and let me know.